# How to expose hidden overloading from base class?

Tags: c++, inheritance, overloading, hidden

Given this code:

```
class base {
public:
  string foo() const; // Want this to be visible in 'derived' class.
}

class derived : public base {
public:
  virtual int foo(int) const; // Causes base class foo() to be hidden.
}
```

How can I make base::foo() visible to derived without replicating it with a dummy method overloading that calls the base class?  Does `using` do the trick, if so, where does it go, is it like this?

```
class derived : public base {
public:
  virtual int foo(int) const;
  using base::foo;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry for the short answer, but yes. It's exactly like this and does what you want:

```
class derived : public base {
public:
  virtual int foo(int) const;
  using base::foo;
};
```

Also note that you can access the base even without `using`:

```
derived x;
string str = x.base::foo(); // works without using
```

Comment: I assume this also works for pointers: x_ptr->base::foo(), right?

Comment: @William: yep. The difference between the two is that `using` pulls all the members of that name to a single scope, so they all participate in overload resolution.

Answer (score 1):

The using directive will make selected methods from base visible to the scope of derived. But from a design point of view this is not desirable, since you're hiding names to the scope of derived while using a public interface. (Doing this with a private interface makes more sense)